# Can て be a particle?

Tags: grammar

Recently in Japan I saw the following sentence:

> お支払いは窓口にて、お願いします。

My husband explained that the emphasis was one could ONLY order at the window.

Being a native speaker, he is unable to really explain the grammar or how to use this.

Comment: "Can て be a particle?" ← I don't understand what you mean... て is a particle(助詞). The て in the te-form such as し**て** , 見**て** , 美しく**て** etc. is a conjunctive particle(接続助詞)

Comment: I thought exactly the same thing as @chocolate. You should have written "Can _this_ て be a particle?" or something.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your question, て is used instead of は sometimes, mostly by younger people.

Answer (score 7):

Particle used here is [にて](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6)--a more formal version of で.

The sentence is equal to the following except for being more official:

> お支払いは窓口で、お願いします。

The sign asks customers to pay at the window.

Similarly to で, [にて](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6-592418) is used to indicate place of the action, time of the action, method, or reason.